# Create dictionary from Fasta file

Tags: python-3.x

I recently picked up a program i started some time ago (sorting and listing of gene code) and since I am a beginner and couldn't find anything about this specific problem online i will need some help.

I want to crate a dictionary from a Fasta (fna) file that looks like this:
(actual file uploaded, the editor distorts everything i copy&paste; I hope that is allowed):
http://www.filedropper.com/firstreads
http://pastebin.com/NNXV09A7 <- smallReads

I know how to make a dictionary manually but i have no idea how i could combine it with reading the dictionary entries from a file.
I appreciate any help.

edit: manual dict from example above:

```
dict= {'ATTC': 'T', 'CATT': 'C'}
```

or using the constructor:

```
dict([('ATTC', 'T'), ('CATT', 'C')])
```

edit2:
Thanks to Byte Commander i was able to make the function by adding the parameters:

```
def makeSuffixDict (inputfile="smallReads.fna", n=15):

my_dict = {}

with open(inputfile) as file:

    for line in file:

        word = line.split()[-1]

        my_dict[word[:-n]] = word[-n:]

return()


if __name__ == "__main__":
makeSuffixDict
for keys,values in my_dict.items():
    print(keys)
    print(values)
    print('\n')
```

However, when I try to change the suffix length, i get the same result. How can i make the suffix length variable?

There is also one small issue and that's the "'': '5'" at the beginning. why is it there and can i make it not show up?

> {'': '5', 'ATTG': 'T', 'GCCC': 'T', 'TTTT': 'T', 'AGTC': 'C'}

Similar to this when I try another file with 30000 reads instead of 5 every now and then numbers pop up and I have no clue where they come from.
Example:

> CAAGATCTAATATGAATTACAGAGAGCTGTTCAGCAAATACTTGTTGCATCAATGGAATTACAGCAGTAACACATATATTGACCTGGAACCAGAATCATGTTCTGAATGCAGAAGTACGTACTTTCTTTTTCTTTCTTGAGAACGCTGGATCTTTTTTAAAATGTTAATTTGCAGTTTGAAGCTGTTTAGGTTAAAAAAAAAATACAAGAAGCAGCAGCAAAAGAGACC : A
>
> 2407 : 9
>
> ATTCTTTCATACCATTAAATATTTATTTTTCAAAACTGATCTTAGTAGAGGCCTAGTACTGTCTCATATAAATATAGGATAATATATATAATAAATCCCCTGACATCAGACATTAAGGTTACTCCCAATTACTTATTATCTTTATATATATGTTAAAAATATGTGTGTATAATATGTAAGTAAACAATTTGCATAGTTTATATGTGGTAATATATGGTTAATATATAGG : C

Comment: Show how you would do it manually and what the resulting dictionary would contain.

Comment: I edited how I would manually make the dictionaries. The prefix is the key, the suffix (of length 1) is the value.

Comment: I wrote down to have the list of reads and suffix length as parameters of the function when i started but i don't remember how i intended to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# create an empty dictionary:
my_dict = {}

# open the file:
with open("file.fna") as file:

    # read the file line by line:
    for line in file:

        # split at whitespace and take the last word:
        word = line.split()[-1]

        # add entry to dictionary: all but the last character -> key; last character -> value
        my_dict[word[:-1]] = word[-1]
```

[See this code running on ideone.com (reading from STDIN instead of file though...)](http://ideone.com/YR0mHN)

**Update:**

If you want variable length suffixes, replace the last line above with this, where `n` is the length of the suffix which becomes the dictionary value:

```
        my_dict[word[:-n]] = word[-n:]
```

[See this code running on ideone.com (reading from STDIN instead of file though...)](http://ideone.com/MXEq7F)

---

**Update 2:**

Your code as stated in the question has some problems with the indentation. Also, there are no braces after `return`, but you need them to call a function. You need to return the dictionary created in the function as well to work with it outside.

I also now parse the 3rd whitespace-separated word in each row instead of the last one. Lines with not exactly 3 words are ignored.

Here's my version:

```
def makeSuffixDict (inputfile="smallReads.fna", n=15):
    my_dict = {}
    with open(inputfile) as file:
        for line in file:
            words = line.split()
            if len(words) == 3:  # <-- replaced "last word" with "3rd word"
                word = words[2]
                my_dict[word[:-n]] = word[-n:]
    return my_dict

if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_dict = makeSuffixDict()
    for key,value in my_dict.items():
        print(key, value)
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, works like a charm. May i bother you with the question if there is a simple way to make that into a function i could later call with the file and suffix length as parameters? i remember why i wrote it down: later on i want to exchange files and try different suffix lengths.

Comment: Nevermind, I found out why my function didn't work. A simple error on my side. I have one last question, tho: As seen in my edit the print shows a "5" in front of the text. Why is that and how can I avoid it?

Comment: @grindbert I don't see any edit from you to your question. Where is a "5"?

Comment: I'm sorry, the editing took longer than the simple copy&paste i expected, because another issue came up.

Comment: @grindbert I updated my answer to allow variable length suffixes. In your attempt, a colon was missing, therefore you only always got one character as value instead of all remaining characters. - And the `'': '5'` is caused by a malformed line that does not follow the syntax you describe. One possible line that might cause this would be `read 5` without following ACGT word. You should ensure that the file format is consistent. Or shall we modify the script that it always parses the 3rd word instead of the last one and that it omits the line of no 3rd word is there?

Comment: I think modifying the script might be better. The Files are consistent as far as i can see. The file ends with a ACGT word after "read 5" which is why i have no clue why it pops up. If it wouldn't it'd be obvious.

Comment: Additionally something weird just happened. I will edit my Code to show the whole program so far. It worked until now but once I restarted Spyder i get an error message in the "for keys,values in my_dict.items():"-line that my_dict is not defined. What would be the best way to print the dict?

Comment: Updated the answer. Now it parses the 3rd word instead of the last one. I also corrected the mistakes in your code that you added to the question. Please consider accepting this answer if it now finally solves your problem. Thanks.

Comment: Now it says "IndexError: list index out of range". I don't even know what this list index is. I'm sure the reason for this error is because the editor didn't show the content of the file as i copy&pasted it. I will edit it without the quote so it doesn't get distorted. And obviously i will accept your answer, you have helped me a great lot.

Comment: Oopy, sorry. There was a little typo on my side ("3" instead of "2") which caused the IndexError. Should work now?

Comment: now it only prints the "5". How can that be? I'm completely confused by now. I'm sorry this problem is taking so much of your time.

Comment: My way of parsing the file relies on the word count of each row. All rows that do not have exactly 3 words are discarded, else the 3rd word (index 2) is processed. Your file format looks different. In your FirstReads file, I see a "> " in front of the line - that counts as word too! I canceled the download of the other huge file after a few MB though. Upload it to a raw text sharing site like pastebin.com and narrow it down to only few lines.

Comment: took an example of the first 5 and uploaded it to pastebin.

Comment: I played around with the code a bit and I got it now. Everything works and the unwanted numbers are gone! Thank you so much, you were a great help.